# Using GPG or PGP, is there a way to give another user (or key) access to decrypt a file for a limited time only?

Tags: gnupg, pgp, file-encryption

I want to share encrypted files with someone else however it's only for a short time only.   What is the best way to do this?

More background: I'd like to add more people to be able to decrypt the file as time goes on and others "expire".    Think of this as when members of a team join and leave and that this constantly happens.

Comment: I think this may be a imitation of PGP and GPG.  I heard that Signal doesn't have this problem however I don't know of a Signal tool that just does file encryption.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easy and obvious solution is to encrypt for multiple recipients:

1. each party should create their own PGP key and provide you with
   their **public key**
2. then you PGP-encrypt the files for all the parties that should be granted access
3. when you decide someone should no longer have access to **future** files you stop adding them to the list of 'recipients'

It is also possible to configure GnuPG so that you don't have to specify the recipients manually every time.
For this you add a line in your `gpg.conf` file with the `encrypt-to` directive followed by the key ID (one line per recipient).

Time-limited access is an oxymoron.